# How to make php run in background on web server? * Always keep running

Tags: php, mysql, apache, server

I have a script that updates the status of some installments in a database according to their due date, but I would need it to run "Always", or at least every day at scheduled times. Is it possible to do this on a web server?

Comment: you can create cron jobs (scheduled tasks) and call that specific script (every second, minute, hour, day etc ) https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

Comment: If you are using Windows, Task Scheduler is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cron jobs for running the script on what ever time combination you want.